# httpContext User Identity

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, httpcontext

I would like to restrict user's access on my website based on the the User Identity and I used following code its works fine in Visual Studio but when I am publishing into IIS sending **userIdentity= NULL** to Database.

```
Dim httpContext__1 As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
Dim winIdentity As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = DirectCast(httpContext__1.User.Identity, WindowsIdentity)
Dim userIdentity As String = winIdentity.Name

hasAccess = GetUserFromDB(userIdentity)
If hasAccess Then
    ' restrictions on 
Else
End If
```

Comment: You seem to have mixed Visual Basic code with Visual C# code. Are you writing in a new language? Visual BasiC# perhaps? :)

Comment: Hi #Visual Vincent 
I am not making new language, just wrote pseudocode but looking like C#.

Comment: As you have the actual code - post that

Comment: Now I have updated with VB  code :)

Comment: I know you aren't making a new language, I was just kidding since you seemed to mix the languages. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to be sure that Windows Authentication is enabled and Anonymous Authentication is disabled.[Please See This Link](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication)